# Selenium Sendkeys fails to work in second attempt in IE9

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an issue with Selenium SendKeys. I created a separate method in Java for sending the details to be filled in for a window using Sendkeys. During first attempt it enters all the configured details and was working fine.

I use the same method after few lines in my code for entering another set of details. But this time it fails to enter the details in window. I can see selenium entering the text and switching to the next tabs, but the text is not visible. I don't see any exception as well.

Can someone please help me with this. Also I am using selenium web driver with IE9.

Thank you,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **driver.findElement(By.id("element")).clear();** before sending **SendKeys**

You are saying it is Entering the text and Switching to Next Tab , IS it entering the **Expected values** ??? which Text is Not Visible ? the Entered one ? if No Exception - the AUT is Designed to Hide the Second entered Text ?

Provide snippets of Code to Check whats happening with the **driver**

Comment: I tried using clear command before sending Sendkeys but still it fails. The Entered tex

Comment: I tried using clear command before sending Sendkeys but still it fails. The Entered text is not visible. But I can sense Selenium typing the keys in tab. Also I don't see any exception.

Comment: @sathish Here is my code snippet                                       
private void AddNewPolicy(String name, String carrriername, String number) {
     driver.switchtoPolicieswindow();
  driver.findElement(By.id("field1")).sendKeys(name);
                          driver.findElement(By.id("field2")).sendKeys(carrriername);
driver.findElement(By.id("field2")).sendKeys(number);
}